# Laravel app I deployed to aws is not working

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I develop a laravel app which I deployed to aws.

using the following steps

I create an ec2 instance which has a security group that allows https from anywhere, ssh from anywhere, mysql from an ip address

loggedin using ssh

changed directory to /var/www/

removed the default html file and created a directory

cd into the directory

updated the server

installed php dependencies, composer and git

pulled my files from git

changed ownership and permission of the directory

After deploying everything worked perfect

this is default.conf

```
<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@ahtcloud.com
    ServerName http://18.189.174.42
    ServerAlias http://18.189.174.42
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laraqueue/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/laraqueue>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</virtualHost>
```

but when I tried loading the page

I get error Connection timed out

Please what could be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Without watching the video (because I have no intention of doing so) I would suggest checking if your security group allows access from outside. Also for other people who don't intend to watch the video I would suggest you also share the steps you took to deploy your application to AWS

Comment: You don't seem to mention running `composer install` in your steps shared. You also might need to change permission and ownership after you've done this as well

Answer (score 1):

1. Clone Repository in server.
2. Cd into directory `cd project_name`.
3. Run `composer install`.
4. Create `.env` file normally that file is ignored by .gitignore.
5. Give permission 775 or change user to www-data for storage, bootstrap directory.

   `chmod -R 775 storage/ bootstrap/` Give permission

   `chown-r www-data storage/ bootstrap/` Change directory owner
6. Run `php artisan key:generate`.
7. Change directory path to your project's public folder in `default.conf` file.

   `/etc/apache2/site-available/default.conf`.

Comment: @Apruv Bhavsar I have updated my question. Kindly check it

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/laraqueue/public>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>`

You have to put public path in directory tag as well

Comment: restart apache after updating .conf file

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/laraqueue/public>  AllowOverride All </Directory>`

Comment: Have you enabled the mod_rewrite?